# Get selected item from sap.m.Select from a sapui5 table column

Tags: sapui5

I am using sap.m.Table, where I have 3 columns, as sap.m.text, sap.m.setect and the last one is button.

My model code

```
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.OData("url");
sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel ,"data");
```

Table view code(cells)

```
var oTemplate = new sap.m.ColumnListItem({
        cells : [
            new sap.m.Text({
                text: "{data>Address}"
            }),
            new sap.m.Select({
                id:"sel",
                items: {
                    path: "data>/OPERATORS", // this is a diffent table
                    template: new sap.ui.core.Item({
                    text: "{data>firstName} {data>lastName}"
                    })
                },
                forceSelection: false

            }),
            new sap.m.Button({
                        text : "Start",
                        press : [oController.onPressStart, oController]
             })
        ]
    });
oTable.bindItems("data>/ORDR", oTemplate); //differnt table
```

Working fine, getting all required data on the specific table.(Notice first column is coming from ORDR table and second one is coming from OPERATORS table).

Now on button click I wanted the specific row data. My code as follows -

```
onPressStart : function(oEvent){  
   var obj = oEvent.getSource().getBindingContext("data").getObject();
   },
```

"obj" gives me ORDR table row objects(where I pressed the button).

Now I also want the value I will select on the dropdown box. How to get it.

Please suggest, Thank you

JSbin Link - http://jsbin.com/quhomoloqo/edit?html,console,output

Comment: you mean `selectControl.getSelectedItem().getText()`?

Comment: please check the JSbin link, in console I am getting the Address when I click the respective button,but  I also want the selected value from the dropdown. How to get it

Comment: You haven't bound the `Select`'s control `selectedKey` property to a `data>/ORDR/???` property

Comment: Hi @Qualiture, Are you referring to this line [//var sel = oEvent.getSelectedItem().getText();] I am binding [data>/OPERATORS], in sap.m.select

Comment: No, I'm missing the databinding for `selectedKey`, i.e. `new sap.m.Select({selectedKey : "{data>whateverpropertyyoustoretheselectedvalue}", items : { etc... }});`

Comment: @Qualiture, selectedKey : "{data>firstName}", but path is "data>/OPERATORS", not data>/ORDR(this is only for the first column)

Comment: I think you don't understand me; `data>/OPERATORS` is where you populate your dropdown with (and has nothing to do with the selected item). `data>/ORDR` is where you populate your table with, so the `selectedKey` property of your dropdown should be bound to a property relative to `data>/ORDR`

Comment: See this example (it uses XMLView paradigm, but same applies to JSView) https://jsbin.com/cohemo/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @Qualiture, I don't have any connection between two tables, I just want to get the respective values on button click.

Comment: data link - http://api.myjson.com/bins/pnon

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106008/discussion-between-qualiture-and-kuljit-k).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this working example:

Please note how (for the sake of this question) created two models: 
One named 'orig' which holds your original `OPERATOR` and `ODRD` data, and
one named 'data' which holds a copy of the `OPERATOR` data, with an added `Address` property.

See the view code on how the two models are used (the new one for the table, the old one for populating the dropdown)

```js
sap.ui.controller("view1.initial", {
    onInit : function(oEvent) {
    },

    onAfterRendering : function() {
        // your original model
        var oModel        = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();

        var oData = {
            "ODRD":[
                {"Address":"UK"},
                {"Address":"US"}
            ],
            "OPERATORS":[
                {"firstName":"a","lastName":"b"},
                {"firstName":"c","lastName":"d"}
            ]
        };

        oModel.setData(oData);

        this.getView().setModel(oModel, "orig");

        // the model you actually need
        var oNewModel     = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();

        var oNewData = oData.OPERATORS.map(function(result) {
            return {
                firstName : result.firstName,
                lastName : result.lastName,
                keyToAddress : null
            }
        })

        oNewModel.setData({
            "OPERATORS" : oNewData
        });

        this.getView().setModel(oNewModel, "data");
    },

    showData : function(oEvent) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(oEvent.getSource().getBindingContext("data").getObject()));
    }
});

sap.ui.xmlview("main", {
    viewContent: jQuery("#view1").html()
})
.placeAt("uiArea");
```

```html
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
    src="https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
    data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"
    data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex"
    data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"></script>

<div id="uiArea"></div>

<script id="view1" type="ui5/xmlview">
    <mvc:View 
      controllerName="view1.initial"
      xmlns="sap.m"
      xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
      xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" >
        <Table id="tbl" items="{data>/OPERATORS}">
            <columns>
                <Column>
                    <Text text="First" />
                </Column>
                <Column>
                    <Text text="Last" />
                </Column>
                <Column>
                    <Text text="ODRD" />
                </Column>
                <Column>
                    <Text text="" />
                </Column>
            </columns>
            <items>
                <ColumnListItem>
                    <cells>
                        <Input value="{data>firstName}" />
                        <Input value="{data>lastName}" />
                        <Select items="{orig>/ODRD}" selectedKey="{data>keyToAddress}">
                            <items>
                                <core:ListItem key="{orig>Address}" text="{orig>Address}" />
                            </items>
                        </Select>
                        <Button text="Show data" press="showData" />
                    </cells>
                </ColumnListItem>
            </items>
        </Table>
    </mvc:View>
</script>
```